# Save Image URL to the User in SailsJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo, sails-skipper

I'm creating an api using Sails JS v1.0.0

I have an action to upload an image to the server and it's working great but the problem I'm having is that I want to save the image URL to the user uploaded the image. It's the user profile image.

The code seems to work fine but I get an error in the terminal after  uploading the image. I guess it has something with the callbacks.

Here is my controller:

```
let fs = require('fs');

module.exports = {

    upload : async function(req, res) {
      req.file('image').upload({ dirname : process.cwd() + '/assets/images/profile' }, function(err, uploadedImage) {
        if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
        let filename = uploadedImage[0].fd.substring(uploadedImage[0].fd.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        let uploadLocation = process.cwd() +'/assets/images/uploads/' + filename;
        let tempLocation = process.cwd() + '/.tmp/public/images/uploads/' + filename;
        fs.createReadStream(uploadLocation).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tempLocation));
        res.json({ files : uploadedImage[0].fd.split('assets/')[1] })
      })
    }

};
```

About the read stream to the .tmp folder, I wrote it to make the image available the moment it gets uploaded.

I tried to query for the user right before the

```
res.json({ files : uploadedImage[0].fd.split('assets/')[1] })
```

line, but it gives me an error in the terminal.

What's the best way to implement this code?

```
User.update({ id : req.body.id }).set({ image : uploadedImage[0].fd.split('images/')[1] });
```

Comment: What is the error message that you get in the terminal?

Comment: if i used 'async' in the upload callback and then updated the user using 'await' i get the following error : Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Haboosh/Desktop/dental/dental-server/assets/images/uploads/0aab9fbb-5419-4787-851e-4469c419a27d.jpg'
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... @MjZac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are uploading images to '/assets/images/profile' and trying to fetch it from '/assets/images/uploads/'. Also wrong path in tempLocation variable too. Change your code to following and it will hopefully start working

```
upload : async function(req, res) {
  req.file('image').upload({ dirname : process.cwd() + '/assets/images/profile' },
  async function(err, uploadedImage) {
  if (err) return res.negotiate(err);
  let filename = uploadedImage[0].fd.substring(uploadedImage[0].fd.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  let uploadLocation = process.cwd() +'/assets/images/profile/' + filename;
  let tempLocation = process.cwd() + '/.tmp/public/images/profile/' + filename;
  fs.createReadStream(uploadLocation).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(tempLocation));

  await User.update({ id : req.body.id }).set({ image : uploadedImage[0].fd.split('images/')[1] });

  res.json({ files : uploadedImage[0].fd.split('assets/')[1] })
})
},
```